# Are there names for these types of convergence of measures?

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

On a measurable space, let $m_n, n=1, \dots, $ be a sequence measures on it and $\mu$ is another measure.

let $Z := \{ϕ∈L^2(\mu): ∫ ϕ\,d\mu = 0 \}$.

The first type of convergence of $m_i$'s is defined as
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \sup_{\phi\in Z:\,\|\phi\|_2=1} \int \phi \, dm_n =0. 
$$
This is motivated by the definition of a stochastic  process being [ρ-mixing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixing_%28mathematics%29).

The second type of convergence of $m_i$'s is defined as
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \sup_{\phi\in Z:\,\|\phi\|_\infty=1} \int \phi \, dm_n =0. 
$$
This is motivated by the definition of a stochastic  process being [α-mixing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixing_%28mathematics%29).

The third type of convergence of $m_i$'s is defined as
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty} \sup_{0\leq\phi\leq1} \Big| \int \phi \, dm_n - \int \phi \, dQ \Big| = 0 
$$
This is motivated by the definition of a stochastic  process being [β-mixing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixing_%28mathematics%29).
A side question: what does $0\leq\phi\leq1$ really means?

Are there names for these types of convergence of measures?
I would like to know about their relations with other types of convergence of a sequence of measures, such as weak and weak* convergence.

I have tried to read [Chen, Xiaohong; Hansen, Lars Peter; Carrasco, Marine (2010). "Nonlinearity and temporal dependence". Journal of Econometrics 155 (2): 155–169.](http://dido.econ.yale.edu/P/cd/d16b/d1652.pdf)  cited in the Wikipedia article for the three types of mixing, and also traced [Mixing Conditions for Markov Chains
Yu. A. Davydov
Theory Probab. Appl. 18-2 (1974)](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/1118033) cited in that paper for the definitions of β-mixing. But I failed to see answers to my above questions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think that $\rho$-convergence is $L^2$ convergence to zero.  For simplicity assume that the measures $m_n$ are absolutely continuous with respect to $\mu$, with Radon-Nikodym density $q_n$.  Then you want
$$
\int q_n^2 d \mu \rightarrow 0.
$$
By Holder's inequality this implies the conergence you give, and if this $L^2$ convergence doesn't hold, you can construct a $\phi$ to violate your condition.

$\alpha$-mixing looks like $L^1$ convergence to zero.  This is
$$
\int q_n d \mu \rightarrow 0.
$$
We don't need absolute values since $q_n$ is nonnegative.  A lot of this is related to duals of $L^p$ spaces.  The dual of $L^2$ is $L^2$, while the dual of $L^\infty$ is $L^1$.

In your definition of $\beta$-mixing, what is $Q$.

Note, for example that $\rho$-mixing is stronger than weak convergence in $L^2$.  That would be equivalent to saying that for each $\phi\in L^2$,
$$
\int \phi q_n d \mu \rightarrow 0,
$$
without saying anything about convergence holding uniformly over all such $\phi$ with $||\phi||_2 = 1$.

Comment: Thanks! In the definition of β-mixing, Q is the measure $M_n$'s converge to.